# Select a row using a foreign key in another table

Tags: postgresql, join, foreign-key

Hi I'm using python and sqlalchemy and postgresql for creating a relational database

I have 2 tables
`Users` and `Connections`
`Users` have information about each user with their `id` as `primary-key`
and `Connections` have their `id` (`Users.id`) as `Foreign-key`
Imagine I add multiple user id into Connections
and after a few moments I want to select a row where the user have specific information in their `Users table` row

for example :

```
Table Users :
    Column id BIGINT primary key
    Column age INTEGER

Table Connections:
    Column user_id BIGINT ForeignKey(Users.id)
    Column Connection_id VARCHAR(100)

SELECT id FROM Connections WHERE Users(Connections.id).age = 20 limit 1;
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly (although it doesn's apply in this case), you should **always** include your version of PostgreSQL with any questions here.

What you are referring to is an `[INNER] JOIN`. The different types of joins are explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-joins/). There are many links on different join types out there.

So, in this case, I would do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE my_user 
(
  id INT  NOT NULL, 
  age INT NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE connection 
(
  connection_id INT NOT NULL, 
  user_id       INT NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (connection_id),
  CONSTRAINT conn_user_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES my_user (id)
);
```

populate them:

```
INSERT INTO my_user VALUES (1, 50), (2, 45), (3, 73);
```

and

```
INSERT INTO connection (user_id, connection_id)
VALUES 
(1, 500), (1, 501), (1, 502), (1, 503), (1, 504),
(2, 601), (2, 602), (2, 603), (2, 604), (2, 605),
(3, 701), (3, 702), (3, 703), (3, 704);
```

And then run the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
  u.id, u.age, c.connection_id, c.user_id
FROM my_user u
JOIN connection c
  ON u.id = c.user_id;
```

Result:

```
id  age     connection_id   user_id
1   50                500   1
1   50                501   1
1   50                502   1
1   50                503   1
1   50                504   1
2   45                601   2
2   45                602   2
2   45                603   2
2   45                604   2
2   45                605   2
3   73                701   3
3   73                702   3
3   73                703   3
3   73                704   3
```

So, you have **all** the information from **both** tables. If you have more fields, you may wish to include or exclude them as per your requirements.

One word of **strong** advice. Do **NOT** store people's ages. Rather, store their birthday and calculate their age from that on the fly!

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_user_bis
(
  id INTEGER, 
  bday TIMESTAMPTZ
);
```

1 record as a sample:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  AGE(CURRENT_DATE, bday::DATE),
  EXTRACT(YEAR from AGE(bday))
FROM my_user_bis;
```

Result:

```
id        bday             age                          date_part
1   2000-05-05 00:00:00+01  21 years 11 mons 16 days    21
```

If you don't store birthdays and do a calculation on the fly, you'll start to get errors - what happens if someone who's 53 now record is accessed in 3 years time - it'll still show him as 53. Unless you implement some sort of horrible hack with  a trigger running at the end of each year! Yuck! My advice is to store birthdays - if the user is happy to provide their age, there's no reason that they wouldn't provide a birthday!

Welcome to dba.se!